# Javascript Object method value not showing with console.log of the object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm a bit confused with objects in JavaScript...

I wrote an object:

```js
const gix = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Johnson",
  yearOfBirth: 2000,
  profession: "IT",
  friends: ["Mark", "Luke", "John"],
  driversLicence: true,
  age: function () {
    this.calcAge = 2022 - this.yearOfBirth;
    return this.calcAge;
  },
};

gix.age();
console.log(gix);
```

Why is the console log of the whole object not showing the calculated value but is showing age: f()

Comment: `age` is a function. The question is, why do you expect it to show you a value? Just imagine if the function accepted parameters, which parameters should it use in order to show you a result? Obviously JavaScript doesn't know it, so it just tells you that the property contains a function

Comment: "*not showing the calculated value*" - but it **does show** `calcAge`, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I understand that.. But the point I wanted to make is that even when I expand all the things that I can open in the function age, I can't find the value inserted (calcAge) anywhere, as someone in the answers got... And I would expect it would show me calcAge since it is in this point calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your use-case, you could replace the method with a *getter*, which gets evaluted each time the object is referenced:

```
const gix = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Johnson",
  yearOfBirth: 2000,
  profession: "IT",
  friends: ["Mark", "Luke", "John"],
  driversLicence: true,
  get age() {
    return 2022 - this.yearOfBirth;
  },
};
```

Comment: A getter shouldn't mutate `this.calcAge` though

Comment: @Bergi that's true, I suppose that the whole reason of existence of `calcAge` just disappears in this case

Comment: Yeah, but I wanted to understand why it doesn't work in this situation :)

Answer (score 0):

You would either want to capture the return value of the function or call it so:

```
console.log(gix.age());
```

Think of age as a pointer to the function...

Answer (score 0):

When you're console logging a function it wont execute it, It will just show the contents of the function, IF you need to see the value then you need to call the function and log the output

`console.log(gix.age());`

Answer (score 0):

If you check the log, it actually added `calcAge` as you already called `age` before. If you want to use a computed property `calcAge` from `yearOfBirth`, you can use Object getters

```js
const gix = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Johnson",
  yearOfBirth: 2000,
  profession: "IT",
  friends: ["Mark", "Luke", "John"],
  driversLicence: true,
  get calcAge () { return 2022 - this.yearOfBirth; },
};

console.log(gix.calcAge);
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. And this shows the value, that is true. But I can't find calcAge anywhere when I run console.log(gix);

Comment: @IgorJevremovic it's showing as the last property if you run the code snippet in the question. Of course, it will only show in ``gix`` after calling ``gix#age``.